# How can I change a widget on screen according a boolean value?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a switch that returns true or false according to the user action. When the value is true, I want to change a specific height in another widgets and change others boolean variables too. Doing this I hope that some widgets become different. However, when I change the values, nothing happens. Below is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CreateMatch extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CreateMatchState createState() => _CreateMatchState();
}

class _CreateMatchState extends State<CreateMatch> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    bool _isSwitched = false;
    bool boolDivider = false;
    bool boolRow = false;
    double heightContainer = height * 0.36; //0.43
    double heightCard = height * 0.102; //0.18

    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage("assets/fundo.png"),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Container(
            height: heightContainer, //36
            width: width,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
            child: Card(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
              ),
              color: Color(0xFFD2DCE8),
              child: Column(
                //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            blurRadius: 0.02
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 10, right: 10),
                    //color: Colors.blue,
                    height: height * 0.102,
                    width: width,
                    child: Card(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)
                      ),
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                            child: Text("Tempo de partida", style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Nunito-Bold", fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Color(0xFF153E7D),
                              shadows: <Shadow>[
                              Shadow(
                                offset: Offset(1.0, 1.0),
                                blurRadius: 1.0,
                                color: Colors.black,
                              )],
                            )),
                          ),
                          InkWell(
                            onTap: (){},
                            child: Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: width * 0.17),child: Image.asset("assets/botao_recuar.png", height: 35,)),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                              color: Colors.green,
                            ),
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            width: width * 0.13,
                            height: 35,
                            child: Text("00:00", style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Nunito-Bold", fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white,
                                shadows: <Shadow>[
                                  Shadow(
                                  offset: Offset(1.0, 1.0),
                                blurRadius: 5.0,
                                color: Colors.black,
                              ),
                              ],
                            )),
                          ),
                          InkWell(
                            onTap: (){},
                            child: Container(child: Image.asset("assets/botao_avancar.png", height: 35,)),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          blurRadius: 0.02
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 10, right: 10),
                    //color: Colors.blue,
                    height: heightCard, //0.102
                    width: width,
                    child: Card(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                                child: Text("Apostas", style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Nunito-Bold", fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Color(0xFF153E7D),
                                  shadows: <Shadow>[
                                    Shadow(
                                      offset: Offset(1.0, 1.0),
                                      blurRadius: 1.0,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                    )],
                                )),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: width * 0.49),
                                child: Transform.scale(
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  scale: 2.0,
                                  child: Switch(
                                    onChanged: (bool val) {
                                      print(_isSwitched);
                                      setState(() {
                                        _isSwitched = val;
                                      });
                                      print(_isSwitched);
                                      if(_isSwitched == true){
                                        setState(() {
                                          boolDivider = true;
                                          boolRow = true;
                                          heightContainer = height * 0.43;
                                          heightCard = height * 0.18;
                                        });
                                      }else{
                                        setState(() {
                                          boolDivider = false;
                                          boolRow = false;
                                          heightContainer = height * 0.36;
                                          heightCard = height * 0.102;
                                        });
                                      }
                                    },
                                    value: _isSwitched,
                                    activeThumbImage: AssetImage("assets/button_switch_green.png"),
                                    inactiveThumbImage: AssetImage("assets/button_switch_red.png"),
                                    activeColor: Colors.green,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),

                            ],
                          ),
                          Visibility(
                            visible: boolDivider,
                            child: Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 5),
                              child: Divider(
                                color: Colors.blue,
                                thickness: 2,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Visibility(
                            visible: boolRow,
                            child: Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                                  child: Text("Valor", style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Nunito-Bold", fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Color(0xFF153E7D),
                                    shadows: <Shadow>[
                                      Shadow(
                                        offset: Offset(1.0, 1.0),
                                        blurRadius: 1.0,
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                      )],
                                  )),
                                ),
                                Stack(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    InkWell(
                                      onTap: (){},
                                      child: Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: width * 0.30),child: Image.asset("assets/botao_recuar.png", height: 35,)),
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                        color: Colors.green,
                                      ),
                                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: width * 0.4, right: 10),
                                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                                      width: width * 0.23,
                                      height: 35,
                                      child: Text("1000", textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Nunito-Bold", fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white,
                                        shadows: <Shadow>[
                                          Shadow(
                                            offset: Offset(1.0, 1.0),
                                            blurRadius: 5.0,
                                            color: Colors.black,
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      )),
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: width * 0.36),
                                      child: Image.asset("assets/moeda.png", width: 38, height: 35,),
                                    ),
                                    InkWell(
                                      onTap: (){},
                                      child: Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: width * 0.65),child: Image.asset("assets/botao_avancar.png", height: 35,)),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),

                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: () => print('hello'),
                        child: Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 30),
                          height: 50.0,
                          width: width * 0.35,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                                image: AssetImage("assets/button_marrom.png"),
                                fit: BoxFit.cover
                            ),
                            //color: green,
                            //border: Border.all(color: Colors.lightGreenAccent, width: 2.0),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                          ),
                          child: Center(child: Text(
                            'Voltar', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Nunito-Bold',
                            fontSize: 25.0, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            shadows: <Shadow>[
                              Shadow(
                                offset: Offset(1.0, 1.0),
                                blurRadius: 3.0,
                                color: Colors.black,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),),),
                        ),
                      ),
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: () => print('hello'),
                        child: Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 30),
                          height: 50.0,
                          width: width * 0.35,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                                image: AssetImage("assets/button.jpeg"),
                                fit: BoxFit.cover
                            ),
                            //color: green,
                            //border: Border.all(color: Colors.lightGreenAccent, width: 2.0),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                          ),
                          child: Center(child: Text(
                            'Jogar', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Nunito-Bold',
                            fontSize: 25.0, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            shadows: <Shadow>[
                              Shadow(
                                offset: Offset(1.0, 1.0),
                                blurRadius: 3.0,
                                color: Colors.black,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),),),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you initialise `heightContainer` and `heightCard` inside build method.

Every time setState called rebuilds the widget, so here  you change `heightContainer` inside setState and then you reinitialise it to `double heightContainer = height * 0.36;`.

You can fix this by doing:

```
class _CreateMatchState extends State<CreateMatch> {
  bool _isSwitched;
  bool boolDivider;
  bool boolRow;
  double heightContainer;
  double heightCard;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _isSwitched = false;
    boolDivider = false;
    boolRow = false;
    heightContainer = 0.0;
    heightCard = 0.0;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    if (_isSwitched) {
      heightContainer = height * 0.43;
      heightCard = height * 0.18;
    } else {
      heightContainer = height * 0.36; //0.43
      heightCard = height * 0.102;
    }
...
```

and i will also change

```
child: Switch(
    onChanged: (bool val) {
      print('_isSwitched $_isSwitched');
      setState(() {
        _isSwitched = val;
        if (_isSwitched == true) {
          boolDivider = true;
          boolRow = true;
        } else {
          boolDivider = false;
          boolRow = false;
        }
      });
...
```